# Deploy ruby on rail app to AWS(Amazon Linux)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am following the step in https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/ to deploy my ruby on rails app to AWS(Amazon Linux). 
I did everything sucessfully except for the setting of nginx.
In the artcile, it asks me to comment out the existing content and paste the following into /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy/contactbook/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
 }
```

But after I installed nginx on Amazon Linux, there is no folder /etc/nginx/sites-available
So I created this folder and file default.
But I got 404 error when I try to access my home page.

Then, I found I have /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, so I updated this file. But when I did sudo service nginx restart, I got error msg as:

```
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Does anyone know how should I do this correctly?

FYI, the content of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf before I broke it:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index   index.html index.htm;

server {
listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

# redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }
# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
#location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
#location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
#location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
listen       443 ssl;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl;
#        server_name  localhost;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        # It is *strongly* recommended to generate unique DH parameters
#        # Generate them with: openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem 2048
#        #ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:$
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Comment: What was the content of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` before you broke it?

Comment: If `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the main conf file (which I assume it is), then you can't have an upstream block outside of the http context. You could, however, have a `stream` block containing an `upstream` block outside of the http context.